# Glassfish error starting domain. endorsed directories not supported

Tags: glassfish, endorsed

I have a problem starting glassfish on Mac Os X 10.14.6.

I installed it with

```
brew install glassfish
```

then I added

```
AS_JAVA="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

in asenv.conf in order to solve a java null pointer exception.

and now I receive the following error:

```
$ ./asadmin start-domain domain1

Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/glassfish/5.1.0/libexec/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/usr/local/Cellar/glassfish/5.1.0/libexec/glassfish/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Command start-domain failed.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are using at least JDK9 to run Glassfish. That's where that error message is coming from. You should see in the log file which JDK is used to run Glassfish. Look for `JVM invocation line`

Comment: it was jdk 12. Now I set jdk 1.8 and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Added it as an answer. Would be glad if you could accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The endorsed directories have been removed since Java 9. So the error message suggests that you are running with at least Java 9.

You need to use Java 8 for this to work. If I remember correctly then Glassfish does not support Java 9 and higher.